# CSV text output from XSLT transformation gets garbled when openend in a third-party application

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, visual-studio-2015, epicorerp

Run into a bit of an issue.

I'm using VS2015 to build up an XSLT that will be used in a 3rd party program. I've generated the sample data from the 3rd party program (Epicor Service Connect) into XML, and have built the XSLT based on that. Now when I debug the stylesheet in VS, I have the expected result - columns up top, seperated by semi-colons, and then each block of data is underneath, as expected.

However, when I run it through the Service Connect program, I get this complete mystery:

[image: Weird symbols rather than data]

I need to be able to return my data in a CSV using semi-colon's as separators. A snip of the data I get in VS shows that this works:

[image: Working data]

And of course, when put into a CSV, it shows the correct information.

XSLT for anyone curious (please be aware this is my 2nd day of using XSLT, prior to this I only knew what it was an abbreviation for - so it's not fantastic - but if you have suggestions on improvement, I happily accept constructive criticism):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:csv="csv:csv" xmlns:message="http://Epicor.com/Message/2.0"
                                                            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                                                            xmlns:ext_UserSchema="http://Epicor.com/SC/UserSchema">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="utf-8" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

<xsl:template match="message:Receiver"/>

<xsl:template match="message:Body">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="message:Req"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="message:Req">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="message:Dta"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="message:Dta">
    <xsl:call-template name="PrimaryDataLoadForESC"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="tessst" select="local-name()"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$tessst = 'QueryResultDataSet'">
            <xsl:call-template name="PrimaryDataLoadNotESC"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="message:Body"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="PrimaryDataLoadNotESC">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/QueryResultDataSet/Results[1]/*" mode="header"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/QueryResultDataSet/Results" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="PrimaryDataLoadForESC">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ext_UserSchema:QueryResultDataSet/ext_UserSchema:Results[1]/*" mode="header"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ext_UserSchema:QueryResultDataSet/ext_UserSchema:Results" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="header">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(local-name(), '_', ' ')"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>;</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="QueryResultDataSet/Results">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="dataNodes"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ext_UserSchema:QueryResultDataSet/ext_UserSchema:Results">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="dataNodes"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*" mode="dataNodes">
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="position()=last()">
            <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>;</xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Some sample data:

**Before Service Connect (post-formatted):**

```
<QueryResultDataSet>
<Results>
    <Source_-_System>SOURCE SYSTEM 1</Source_-_System>
    <Customer>96247</Customer>
    <Description_-_Short>COMPANY DESCRIPTION SHORT</Description_-_Short>
    <Description_-_Medium>COMPANY DESCRIPTION MEDIUM</Description_-_Medium>
    <Description_-_Long>COMPANY DESCRIPTION LONG</Description_-_Long>
</Results>
```

**After Service Connect:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<msg:Msg xsi:schemaLocation="http://Epicor.com/Message/2.0 http://scshost/schemas/epicor/ScalaMessage.xsd" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:msg="http://Epicor.com/Message/2.0">
<msg:Hdr>
    <msg:Ctrl>
        <msg:MsgID></msg:MsgID>
    </msg:Ctrl>
    <msg:Sender>
        <msg:Name></msg:Name>
        <msg:Subname></msg:Subname>
    </msg:Sender>
    <msg:Logon></msg:Logon>
</msg:Hdr>
<msg:Body>
    <msg:Req msg-type="DocumentToProcess" action="MapAndProcess">
        <msg:Dta>
            <ext_UserSchema:QueryResultDataSet xmlns:msg="http://Epicor.com/InternalMessage/1.1" xmlns:ext_UserSchema="http://Epicor.com/SC/UserSchema">
                <ext_UserSchema:Results>
                    <ext_UserSchema:Source_System>SOURCE_SYS1</ext_UserSchema:Source_System>
                    <ext_UserSchema:Vendor>96247</ext_UserSchema:Vendor>
                    <ext_UserSchema:Description_-_Short>COMPANY DESCRIPTION SHORT</ext_UserSchema:Description_-_Short>
                    <ext_UserSchema:Description_-_Medium>COMPANY DESCRIPTION MEDIUM</ext_UserSchema:Description_-_Medium>
                    <ext_UserSchema:Description_-_Long>COMPANY DESCRIPTION LONG</ext_UserSchema:Description_-_Long>
                </ext_UserSchema:Results>
            </ext_UserSchema:QueryResultDataSet>
        </msg:Dta>
    </msg:Req>
</msg:Body>
</msg:Msg>
```

Anyone out there have any ideas as to what could be causing this issue?

Comment: I could help you with the XSLT, but that would require a little bit more input: do you know what the actual required change in the output is to make it work with Service Connect? Or can you create an example by hand that will work with Service Connect, and one that clearly does not? Also, a (minimal) input data XML example would be very welcome.

Comment: Btw, from the screenshot, my first guess is that there's an encoding issue. I.e., the stylesheet will create UTF-8, but given that you create CSV, the expected format for Service Connect may be ISO-8859-1, or try even US-ASCII as a last resort (you can set this in `xsl:output`). And are you sure the CSV must be separated with `;`? Typical CSV is with `,` (the C standing for Comma, not Semicolon ;).

Comment: Hi @Abel, thanks for getting back to me. We require the headers to have the underscores (_) stripped and replaced with spaces ( ) for the output CSV columns. I will edit the question and provide the two sample datasets I am using that achieve the result above. I will give the encoding a shot - that is a good point, could well and truly be that. As for the CSV being seperated with semicolon's, we have made the default language format take the semicolon as a separator as the values may contain commas but not semicolons.

Comment: Small subset of sample data provided. I will now test the different encoding types.

Comment: Ok, I'll await your update (I'll be gone soon, but will see it tomorrow, or someone else will). About your XSLT skills after 2 days, I'm impressed, you've made very good progress and seem to understand templating, patterns, namespaces, the focus, context node, position, and modes, so you must have read good resources or a good teacher. Thumbs up!

Comment: A very patient manager and a great community in StackOverflow help greatly in my learning :) I have tried using the ISO-8859-1 encoding, however I have the same result. The original expected encoding was UTF-16, however, so I may try understanding encoding before trying to change the XSLT again. I may also play around in the 3rd Party software and see if maybe I can check if there is something small I am missing. Thanks for your help!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the stylesheet - it produces valid CSV. So, it is definitely either a) the 3rd party service which messes things up, or b) simply expects input XML or XSLT in a format other than the one you're sending, or c) returns the CSV result in a format other than the one you're expecting. The user manual or developers of that service might clear up b) and c).

Comment: The input is XML; the output is CSV. Hence the reason I am modifying the XSLT. I have produced close to a valid CSV minus the headers from the 3rd party software, and then added my template for the headers (which works fine in VS2015) but fails to output into the CSV with the headers.

Comment: Hmm, are you saying that it works when you add the headers manually, but not when you add them in the CSV? Perhaps the line-ending is wrong (but you seem to use 0xD everywhere)?

Comment: I thought it could have been the line ending - but when I run it through a much more basic (no when/choose clause) stylesheet, I get the same result I am after as in the picture provided within Visual Studio 2015 but within the Service Connect software, I get the CSV minus the headers (i.e Row 1 is data, not the headers). I would understand if it was not displaying data as well, but just the headers has me lost - and also the fact that it works in VS2015 and not in this third party software has me thinking it could be something I'm missing that's within that software.

Comment: Have you already tried "by hand"? I.e., start with a CSV with one header, one column, one row and work with that until it gets imported? Or take a working CSV, truncate it as short as you can, adjust the stylesheet to create exactly the same CSV and do a binary compare if it still fails.

Comment: As you can find in my answer, I strongly believe you hit the BOM-issue, which some supposedly Unicode-capable tools do not properly support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm surprised I didn't spot this earlier:

Your rendering goes wrong because of the [byte order mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)! The first character is the rendering in [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), [CP1252 (windows)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) or Unicode of [0xFF 'ÿ'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ff/index.htm) and the second [0xFE 'þ'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thorn_%28letter%29), which are the first and second byte in a byte order mark when using UTF-16 (order depending on endianness), or when using UTF-8 and you apply the UTF-8 decoding (the bytes being 0xEF, 0xBB 0xBF).

So, in short, to solve this, change the `xsl:output` to contain:

```
<xsl:output byte-order-mark="no" />
```

But this will only work with XSLT 2.0 or up. If you cannot switch to XSLT 2.0, you should check the documentation of your processor if it supports a UTF-8 encoding without the byte-order-mark.

At least at some point, [the Saxon processor output a byte order mark](http://sourceforge.net/p/saxon/mailman/message/22141015/) when using text output with UTF-8. Also, on Windows, Notepad and many other editors automatically emit the byte-order mark when saving a file (if you post-edit your CSV by hand, this may happen, for instance).

To resolve this either:

- Switch to XSLT 2.0 with any which processor
- Post-process your output to remove the byte order mark
- Check the documentation of your third-party software if it has an option to remove or ignore the byte-order mark
- Use a different encoding that does not output the byte-order mark

Comment: Nice suggestions, plus one.

Comment: Sorry @Abel, I was away from work for the past few days. I will try this now and get back to you :) Thanks for your help!

Comment: Worked a dream. Thanks very much for your help Abel! :)